# Lubuntu is Not Booting After Installing From a Bootable Flash Drive

Tags: boot, lubuntu, live-usb

I created a bootable 4gb micro SD card and installed Lubuntu on my laptop, but it won't boot. Instead, I am stuck at a blank screen.

Hardware: 4gb ram, 500HDD, amdA6, dual core,

Lubuntu release: 20.04.4 LTS, desktop image amd64 64bit

Created my flashdrive using the "Startup Disk Creator" app on Lubuntu (from live USB flash drive).

Comment: Did you use the try option before the install option to test out your hardware?

Comment: yes i did i usually do that after every install.it was working fine except internet connection,i thought it will be working after installation. i used sd card and a card reader to create my bootable drive

Comment: I think you mean *before* every install, isn't it? Please [edit] the question and (1) post hardware specifications of the target computer, (2) Lubuntu release, (3) *how* did you made the installation media.

Comment: Thank you for adding the requested info. Now, did you booted and installed in UEFI mode? Ping me @ChanganAuto in the comment so I'm notified.

Comment: no i have not used uefi it was not an option as it is disabled

Comment: So that is likely the beginning of your problems. Any 10 years old or newer computer has UEFI, not BIOS, and should be installed in UEFI mode. Make sure to make the necessary changes in UEFI settings to enable UEFI mode ONLY (disable CSM/Legacy). Then boot a live session, open Gparted > Device menu > create a new partition table... > choose "GPT" (optional but strongly recommended). Then install as usual (by disabling the CSM/Legacy options the installer is assuredly booted in the proper mode and so will be the installation).